# Grep String that contains only two number

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

I have a Sample file which contains strings as

```
GABCDF64V3
HABDDF61WE
KABSDF6WER
HAADYF6WE2
```

I need only values which strings contain two numbers only(Anywhere in the string), Means output should be **HABDDF61WE** and **HAADYF6WE2** only.

I tried this expression

```
grep -E '.*[0-9]{1,}.*[0-9]{1,}.*'
```

But the output is different

Comment: Do you mean _numbers_ or _digits_? The string `GABCDF64V3` clearly contains two decimal numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this in grep, you'd need the *whole line* to consist of zero or more non-digits, followed by a digit, followed by zero or more non-digits, followed by a digit, and finishing off with zero or more non-digits. So for example

```
$ grep -x '[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*' file
HABDDF61WE
HAADYF6WE2
```

(Latin decimal digits only) or

```
$ grep -Px '\D*\d\D*\d\D*' file
HABDDF61WE
HAADYF6WE2
```

If your grep implementation doesn't provide the `-x` / `--line-regexp` option, you can use `^` and `$` line anchors:

```
$ grep '^[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*$' file
HABDDF61WE
HAADYF6WE2
```

Alternatively you may find the whole thing simpler in something like `awk` ex.

```
$ awk 'gsub(/[[:digit:]]/,"&") == 2' file
HABDDF61WE
HAADYF6WE2
```

(`gsub` returns the number of replacements). You could do something similar with Perl's `tr`.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F '[0-9]' 'NF==3' file
```

After splitting by digits, lines with 3 fields are the ones that have 2 digits.